# compiling ffmpeg on msys2 and mingw32-- error creating ffmpeg_g.exe

Tags: ffmpeg, mingw32, msys2

**I have compiled ffmpeg from source using MSYS2 and MinGW.  The library files were created successfully during the compilation and when make utility proceeds to build ffmpeg_g, I am getting lot of undefined references.Kindly tell me why the compilation fails....
    Thanks in advance**

The following library files were generated successfully

```
libavcodec.a
libavdvice.a 
libavfilter.a 
libavformat.a 
libavutil.a 
libpostproc.a
libswresample.a
libswscale.a
```

Command passed for compiling ffmpeg_g.exe output taken by using -d option with mke

```
g++ -Llibavcodec -Llibavdevice -Llibavfilter -Llibavformat -Llibavresample -Llibavutil -Llibpostproc -Llibswscale -Llibswresample -Wl,--nxcompat -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,-rpath-link=libpostproc:libswresample:libswscale:libavfilter:libavdevice:libavformat:libavcodec:libavutil:libavresample  -o ffmpeg_g.exe ffmpeg_opt.o ffmpeg_filter.o ffmpeg.o cmdutils.o  -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavcodec -lpostproc -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lavicap32 -lpsapi -lole32 -lstrmiids -luuid -lws2_32 -lx264 -lvpx -lvpx -lvpx -lvpx -lvorbisenc -lvorbis -logg -lopenjpeg -lmp3lame -lfdk-aac -lfaac -lbluray -L/mingw32/lib -lass -lm -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lexpat -lfreetype -lexpat -lenca -lm -lfribidi -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lws2_32 -lole32 -lwinmm -lshlwapi -lintl -lfreetype -lz -lbz2 -lm -lbz2 -lz -lpsapi -ladvapi32 -lshell32
```

The output from gcc is given below

```
ffmpeg_opt.o: In function new_output_stream:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:1036: undefined reference to avcodec_get_context_defaults3
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:1089: undefined reference to av_get_exact_bits_per_sample
ffmpeg_opt.o: In function find_codec_or_die:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:514: undefined reference to avcodec_find_encoder_by_name
ffmpeg_opt.o: In function choose_encoder:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:965: undefined reference to avcodec_find_encoder
ffmpeg_opt.o: In function find_codec_or_die:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:518: undefined reference to avcodec_find_encoder
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:514: undefined reference to avcodec_find_decoder_by_name
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:518: undefined reference to avcodec_find_decoder
ffmpeg_opt.o: In function add_input_streams:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:596: undefined reference to av_codec_get_lowres
ffmpeg_opt.o: In function choose_decoder:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:546: undefined reference to avcodec_find_decoder
ffmpeg_opt.o: In function add_input_streams:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:546: undefined reference to avcodec_find_decoder
ffmpeg_opt.o: In function open_input_file:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:872: undefined reference to avcodec_get_class
ffmpeg_opt.o: In function add_input_streams:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:631: undefined reference to avcodec_find_decoder
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/ffmpeg_opt.c:595: undefined reference to avcodec_find_decoder
```

> **lot of undefined references followed by**

```
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/libavcodec/mlpdsp.c:64: undefined reference to ff_mlpdsp_init_x86
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(mpegaudiodsp.o): In function ff_mpadsp_init:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/libavcodec/mpegaudiodsp.c:46: undefined reference to ff_mpadsp_init_x86
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(cavsdsp.o): In function ff_cavsdsp_init:
E:\software\pkg\ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar\ffmpeg-2.1.3\ffmpeg-2.1.3/libavcodec/cavsdsp.c:565: undefined reference to ff_cavsdsp_init_x86
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Make  output**

```
LD ffmpeg_g.exe
Reaping losing child 01584DA0 PID 29691080 
Makefile:105: recipe for target ffmpeg_g.exe failed
Removing child 01584DA0 PID 29691080 from chain.
```

Comment: Coudl you please post the full output to pastebin or a gist or something (of running make -V)?

Comment: Hi.. I have pasted the full output to the following link:http://pastebin.com/8Hn81jGi

Comment: ok, now full output of doing "make -V" please

Comment: oops, I meant `make V=1` LOL

Comment: hi.. sorry i didnt understand, i am still a no vice ... i have pasted the output of make V=1 to: http://pastebin.com/Ps3Z5RJC. thanks for the help...

Comment: These are the last two lines: Makefile:105: recipe for target 'ffmpeg_g.exe' failed
make: *** [ffmpeg_g.exe] Error 1

Comment: assuming the file libavcodec\libavcodec.a exists and "is larger than size 0" how was it configured? If you're using --enable-shared it could be related to a poor dependency lib, see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/282

Comment: possibly try with cross compiling and/or mingw-w64 instead...

Comment: @rogerdpack Thanks a lot for the help... The problem was with libavcodec.a. The library was not created completly using cmd.exe.The symbols were missing.I used bash instead for compiling and got it finally.